# Python: use item in the list as function arguments

Tags: python

I have to program this [puzzle](https://wordplay.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/05/20/dark-2/) and solve it (I'm using 100 coins instead of 26), and currently all I have are:

```
def flip():
    if (coin == 0):
        coin = 1
    if (coin == 1):
        coin = 0

def move():
    table_one.remove(coin)
    table_two.append(coin)

def CoinPuzzle():
    table_one = [[1]*20 + [0]*80]
    table_two = []
    #Move 20 coins from table_one to table_two
    #Flip all 20 coins in table_two
    #Both tables should have an equal number of 1s
```

I have a hard time linking individual coin objects with items in the list so that I can execute flip and move functions. I'm new to Python, can someone guide me how to do this?

NEW EDIT: How should I modify the code if I have input like this:

```
L=[0]*100
for i in random.sample(range(100),20):
   L[i]=1
[L1,L2]=tables(L)
```

Comment: The functions `flip` and `move` need parameters and return values. You may want to read more about function design before attempting to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is small python implementation:

```
import random
heads_count = 20
total_coins = 100

table_one = [True] * heads_count + [False] * (total_coins-heads_count)
table_two = []

def flip(table, coin):
    table[coin] = not table[coin]

def move_random():
    coin = random.randint(0, len(table_one)-1)
    table_two.append(table_one[coin])
    del table_one[coin]

for i in range(heads_count):
    move_random()

for i in range(heads_count):
    flip(table_two, i)

print(sum(table_one))
print(sum(table_two))
```

Comment: `len([c for c in table_one if c])` is `sum(table_one)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to Stephen's version. To make the output easier to read I'll use the numbers from the original puzzle.

We use the `shuffle` function to randomize the order of the coins in `table_one` in a single step, then use slicing to move `heads_count` coins from `table_one` to `table_two`. To flip the coins, we use the fact that 1 - 0 = 1 and 1 - 1 = 0.

```
from random import seed, shuffle

# seed the randomizer so we get repeatable results
seed(42)

total_coins = 26
heads_count = 10

# Put all the coins in table_one and randomize their order
table_one = [1] * heads_count + [0] * (total_coins - heads_count)
shuffle(table_one)

print('Initial')
print('Table one:', table_one, sum(table_one), len(table_one))

# move heads_count coins to table_two
table_one, table_two = table_one[heads_count:], table_one[:heads_count]

#flip all the coins in table_two
table_two = [1 - coin for coin in table_two]

print('Final')
print('Table one:', table_one, sum(table_one), len(table_one))
print('Table two:', table_two, sum(table_two), len(table_two))
```

**output**

```
Initial
Table one: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] 10 26
Final
Table one: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] 8 16
Table two: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 8 10
```

We could even combine the last two steps into a single statement:

```
table_one, table_two = table_one[heads_count:], [1 - coin for coin in table_one[:heads_count]]
```